# Android expected android.support.v4.app.Fragment for CameraFragment subclass

Tags: android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

The fragment manager looks like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, ReviewFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, RedeemFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, MyAccountFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 3:
            ParseUser.logOut();
            presentLoginActivity();
            break;
    }
```

and the error is on the line:

```
case 0: 
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, ReviewFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                    .commit();
```

and the error reads:

```
Wrong second argument type. Found: 'blah.blah.blah.MainActivity.ReviewFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
```

The CameraFragment is from cwac-camera-0.6.12.jar

```
public static class ReviewFragment extends CameraFragment

    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static ReviewFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        ReviewFragment fragment = new ReviewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ReviewFragment() {
    }

    ...
}
```

I know that the CameraFragment is android.app.Fragment and I've tried changing the getSupportFragmentManager(); to getFragmentManager(); and change all the other Fragment subclasses to subclass of android.app.Fragment but it still doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: If your minimum SDK is >= 11 you can use native fragments with `getFragmentManager()` along with support fragments with `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Also cwac-camera library is deprecated, is it not?

Comment: @EugenPechanec: It's not deprecated yet, though I am working on a replacement library that overcomes some of the original library's key limitations.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare I've tried both the regular and v9 installations and neither works for various reasons. Is this because of the (near) deprecation? Or am I most likely goofing something up.

Comment: @BryceLanglotz: I can't help you with unspecified "various reasons". I posted an answer yesterday with a recommended approach to creating a fragment that will work for you. If you are running into problems with that approach, post comments on that answer with more details of what those problems are.

Answer (score 1):

My CWAC-Camera library has two fragment implementations:

- one for native API Level 11+ fragments
- one for `SherlockFragment`, for the ActionBarSherlock action bar backport, for historical reasons

It does not contain a fragment that simply extends the fragment backport's `Fragment` class.

That being said, creating your own should take just a couple of minutes. Copy [this class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/camera-v9/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/acl/CameraFragment.java) into your project and change it to extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `SherlockFragment`. In a quick scan of the code, I don't see any other changes that would need to be made.